# Using PCSC in PHP

Tags: smartcard, php-5.6, apdu, pcsc

I am trying to connect smart cards via PHP but I am not connecting to smart cards. I can not run PHP codes. I am working on Linux.

Here the PHP codes are below:

```
<?php
$context = scard_establish_context();
//var_dump($context);

$readers = scard_list_readers($context);
//var_dump($readers);

$reader = $readers[0];
echo "Using reader: ", $reader, "\n";

$connection = scard_connect($context, $reader);
//var_dump($connection);

$CMD = "00A404000AA00000006203010C0601";
$res = scard_transmit($connection, $CMD);
var_dump($res);

$CMD = "00000000";
$res = scard_transmit($connection, $CMD);
var_dump($res);
echo pack("H*", $res), "\n";

scard_release_context($context);

?>
```

The errors I am gettings are below:

> Warning: scard_list_readers() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/pcsc.php on line 8
>
> Warning: scard_connect() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/pcsc.php on line 16
>
> Warning: scard_transmit() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/pcsc.php on line 21
>
> Warning: scard_transmit() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/html/pcsc.php on line 26
>
> Warning: scard_release_context() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/pcsc.php on line 31

I installed PCSC on Linux. I referenced pcsc.so library in php.ini file. I set extension_dir in php.ini.

I did everything but nothing working. What can I do about it?

Comment: What exactly is your return value of `scard_establish_context()`. You should check for errors.

Comment: scard_establish_context() return value is false.

Comment: I pretty much assumed that. You need to find out why it is false. Maybe you need to give your php script elevated execution permission (admin) or maybe your smart card reader is not PC/SC compliant? What reader are you using and what OS is it running on?

Comment: I am using HID Omnikey 3121 Smart Card Reader and I am working on Debian Jessie. I am quite sure Smart Card Reader is PC/SC compliant. Because, I can use this reader on windows another application.

Comment: Yes, I know this reader and it is compliant. You can try http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-get-last.php right after `scard_establish_context()` to see if you get a error code. Then you can further investigate.

Comment: Okey, thank you for your interesting.